# Alterar cor de uma Error Message utilizando Annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, annotation

Onde posso mudar a cor dessa `ErrorMessage`?

[image: Onde mudo a cor dessa Error Message?]

Comment: Como está seu código, especialmente a *view* e CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe algumas formas de como fazer isso.

#### Apenas com CSS

Segundo [A Microsoft](https://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/validating-user-input-in-aspnet-web-pages-sites#Formatting_Validation_Errors) essas são as classes de erros que você terá:

- **field-validation-error**. Defines the output of the Html.ValidationMessage method when it's displaying an error.
- **field-validation-valid**. Defines the output of the Html.ValidationMessage method when there is no error.
- **input-validation-error**. Defines how  elements are rendered when there's an error. (For example, you can use this class to set the background color of an  element to a different color if its value is invalid.) This CSS class is used only during client validation (in ASP.NET Web Pages 2).
- **input-validation-valid**. Defines the appearance of  elements
  when there is no error.
- **validation-summary-errors**. Defines the output of the
  Html.ValidationSummary method it's displaying a list of errors.
- **validation-summary-valid**. Defines the output of the
  Html.ValidationSummary method when there is no error.

Com isso, basta sobrescrever o **CSS** para essas classes, desta forma:

```
<style>
.validation-summary-errors {
  border:2px solid red;
  color:red;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin:6px;
  width:30%;
}

.field-validation-error{
  color:red;
   font-weight:bold;
   background-color:yellow;
}

.input-validation-error{
  color:red;
  font-weight:bold;
  background-color:pink;
}
</style>
```

#### Adicionando uma nova classe à mensagem

Você pode adicionar a sua classe estilizada aos `ValidationMessageFor()`, desta forma:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Name, new { @class ="sua-classe-estilizada"})
```

E em seu **CSS**, você teria sua classe:

```
<style>
    .sua-classe-estilizada{
        color: white;
    }
</style>
```

#### Por DataAnnotation

> Não aconselho essa forma por **N** motivos, mas irei demonstrar que é possível.

Caso queira adicionar algo via `DataAnnotations`, você pode fazer algo aprecido com isso:

```
public class EmployeeMetadata
{
    [Required]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, 
     ErrorMessage = "<img src='/images/error.png' /> 
      Invalid EmployeeID!")]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20, 
     ErrorMessage = "<img src='/images/error.png' /> 
      Invalid first name!")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20, 
     ErrorMessage = "<img src='/images/error.png' /> 
      Invalid last name!")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

E em sua `View` ficaria assim:

```
@Html.Raw(
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.EmployeeID).ToHtmlString()
))
```

Dessa forma, o resultado seria isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: [binaryintellect](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/5caea771-ddd5-4386-bca0-edc898730d3f.aspx)

Existem outras formas, como retorno via Ajax, mensagens customizadas de retorno via jQuery, e o que sua mente imaginar, pois o Razor é "convertido" em HTML ao "compilar".

Answer (score 2):

Normalmente você muda isso no CSS (normalmente encontrado em `~/Content/css`). Veja os estilos:

- `.field-validation-error` - diretamente o que deseja
- `.input-validation-error` - auxiliar se quiser modificar o próprio campo quando a erro
- `.validation-summary-errors` - usado se há um resumo de erros separado

Todos eles possuem uma contrapartida para o estado válido que pode ser usado também. Em geral ele deve estar no estado normal ou esconder a informação de erro.

Você pode fazer na *view*, mas não costuma ser a melhor forma, a não ser que tenha alguma condição específica que não pode ser usada no CSS:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Restaurante, "", new { @style = "color : yellow" })
```

Não faz sentido colocar na anotação. Cada coisa no seu lugar. É possível usar HTML/CSS *inline*. Mas pra que? Na *view* de forma condicional é compreensível, ainda que não consigo ver muita utilidade (vejo alguma), mas colocar algo que é fixo na aplicação vai contra a tecnologia que está usando. Mudar no CSS externo é até mais flexível.

Se quiser insistir seria algo assim:

```
[ErrorMessage = "<p style = 'color : blue;'>Preencha o nome do restaurante</p>")]
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/ErrorMessage.cs).